# Create a new column with new labels

Tags: r

Taking the numbers in the column numbers:

```
data <- data.frame(ci = c(name = c("sth", "another", "more"), numbers = c(1,2,7))
```

How is it possible to create a new column where when the row of the number column has the number 1 or 2 insert in the row of the new column the text "google" and the same when the number is 7 insert the text "yahoo"

```
data.frame(ci = c(name = c("sth", "another", "more"), numbers = c(1,2,7), match = c("google", "google", "yahoo"))
```

Comment: Please check your examples.  There is no `7` and how is it creating 'yahoo'

Comment: @akrun thank you, updated!

Comment: There is an issue in the strucutre of your data. I assume you meant `df <- data.frame(ci = c("sth", "another", "more"), numbers = c(1, 2, 7))`

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(match = case_when(numbers %in% 1:2 ~ 'google', numbers == 7 ~ 'yahoo'))`

Comment: @akrun thank you is it possible to use something like this c(1,2) instead 1:2?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by creating a logical expression in `case_when`.  if none of the conditons are TRUE, by default, it returns `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(match = case_when(numbers %in% c(1, 2) ~ 'google', 
        numbers == 7 ~ 'yahoo'))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ci = c("sth", "another", "more"), numbers = c(1, 2, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data$match[with(data, ci %in% c(1,2))] <- 'google'
data$match[with(data, ci %in% c(7))] <- 'yahoo'
data

#              ci  match
#name1        sth   <NA>
#name2    another   <NA>
#name3       more   <NA>
#numbers1       1 google
#numbers2       2 google
#numbers3       7  yahoo
```